# Jenkins : Dynamically make the parameter available in UI while building job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Assume I have a job at jenkins . and am trying to build it with parameters.
Assume I have 2 parameters say **para1** and **para2**.

**para1** is of choice type parameter with 'yes' and 'No' value

I want **para2** to be available in the UI only when 'yes' is selected in **para1**. otherwise i dont want this parameter itself displayed in the UI

We have following plugins

1. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin
2. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Reactive+Reference+Dynamic+Parameter+Controls

but these will allow to dynamically return values for a parameter based on any reference i.e any prev paramter value,

but not to disable a parameter itself from a job while it builds, like the user should not see the parameter name itself in UI while building the job , in my case **para2** should not be seen when 'No' selected in **para1** ...

any suggestion or workaround to acheive my scenario ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. A Jenkins job is defined by XML, displaying a new parameter based on a value of another one means that the XML definition of the job should be changed and the job reloaded again.
What you can do is to have both parameters displayed in the job and then just use a simple if statement in your Jenkins pipeline to ignore **para2** in case **para1** value is no.

```
if (para1 == 'yes'){
    print "Do something that takes into account ${para2}"
} else {
    print "${para2} value is ignored"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rvelaz . it makes sense to me.. I am using the same plugins which i mentioned in my question.... mainly the active reference dynamic parameter plugin... this has option to return formatted html values... So based on the value in the 'Para1' , i am deciding i should return an html input box to the user to key in the 'Para2'... or just give a message to user this para isn't needed for building the job....

Comment: @MusaffirLp if you think the answer is ok, mark it as answered